# Symfony 2 : Redirect a user to a page if he has a specific role

Tags: redirect, symfony, firewall, roles, access-control

I have a little question.
I want that wherever is the user on my website, if he have the role "ROLE_DEGRADE", he is redirected on a specific page.

How I can do that, I have to use firewall ?
I don't want to redirect the user to a form login, just to a simple page.
I want that everywhere on my website, without put a "if role degrade..." everywhere, in all my controllers...

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: You will probably want to use an event listener.  Don't have a good example handy but it should be straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do it ...

Create a new listener :

```
class AccessListener
{
    private$security;
    private $router;

    public function __construct($security, $router)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_DEGRADE')) {
           $url = $this->router->generate('<route name>');
           $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
        }
    }
}
```

Add it to your `services.yml` :

```
services:
  access_listener:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Listener\AccessListener
    arguments: [ @security.context, @router ]
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Docs :

- [Checking roles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-control-in-controllers)
- [Event Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)
- [Generating URLs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls)

Comment: Great, I just need to add a "if" test to know if i'm not on the "URL page", to avoid infinit loop. Also I have a problem : the debug toolbar display me an alert, so i disable it but dis you know how i can do ?

Comment: @user2178964 check the route - if its the toolbar ignore it